# what is the data type for reading a nano second value?

Tags: c++, c, types

I am reading a nano second value and want to store it in a specific variable, so that I wont loss data. Could someone tell me what could be the data type ??

example :

```
struct timespec ts;
getrawmonotonic(&ts);
end_time = timespec_to_ns(&ts);
```

what could be the data type for end_time ??

Comment: Well, what function are you using to read it?

Comment: Do you mean a point in time in nanosecond resolution? Or a duration of time measured in nanoseconds?

Comment: It can't be negative...is one of its property...so you can use an unsigned data type. Similarly, check for the maximum range, you may read.

Comment: Do you have a machine that gives you nanosecond resultion?

Comment: shall i use double or s64 ??

Comment: I want to store the nanosecond time in a variable of a particular type, so that wont loss the nanosecond data.

Comment: I am having a real time operating system with embedded target.

Comment: `struct timeval` looks as what you're after.

Comment: `uint64_t` most probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of timespec_to_ns looks like this:

```
/**
 * timespec_to_ns - Convert timespec to nanoseconds
 * @ts:         pointer to the timespec variable to be converted
 *
 * Returns the scalar nanosecond representation of the timespec
 * parameter.
 */
static inline s64 timespec_to_ns(const struct timespec *ts)
{
        return ((s64) ts->tv_sec * NSEC_PER_SEC) + ts->tv_nsec;
}
```

So you should store it in a 64-bit integer.

Comment: how to convert nanosecond value to millisecond ??

Comment: divide it by a million. If you want to store it as a floating point value, use the best available precision - simply assign it to a double.

Comment: uint64_t is same as double ??

Comment: no. uint64_t is a 64-bit integer. double is a floating point value (usually 64 bits, but in theory it can be anything)

Answer (score 3):

In C++, this would be [std::chrono::nanoseconds](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). For example, to find the length of (wall-)time taken to execute some code, you could write:

```
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock.now();

//do some things
//...

auto end = std::chrono::system_clock.now();
std::chrono::nanoseconds nanoseconds_taken =
    duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start);
std::cout << "Took: " << nanoseconds_taken.count() << " nanoseconds\n";
```

Comment: I modified my question.

Comment: You may need a duration cast (`duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start)`), since the duration type of `system_clock` is not necessarily implicitly convertible to `nanoseconds`.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the exact specification of `timespec_to_ns`.

[For linux](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/time.h), the type is `s64`. On your own system, you should be able to determine the type by looking in the header that declares `timespec_to_ns`.

In the general case (for C++ only), you can use `auto` to automatically deduce the correct return type:

```
struct timespec ts;
auto end_time = timespec_to_ns(&ts);

//Convert to milliseconds:
auto millis = end_time/1000000.
```

Comment: how to convert nanosecond value to millisecond ??

Comment: Divide by `1000000` (perhaps after converting to a floating-point type).

Comment: how to convert that into floating point ?? which data type should I use to store the value after converting it ?? could you give a example ??

Comment: @user3615655: I've added an example. If you remove the `.` after `1000000.`, it will divide by an integer instead and you will get an integral result.

Comment: uint64_t is same as double ??

Comment: @user3615655: I'd recommend you read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on c++. These are very basic questions. At the very least, have a look through the [language reference on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language).